# Support for Universal-Character-Names optional in C++11?

Tags: c++, unicode, c++11

While sifting through the new C++11 spec, I can not find anything that says *the support of universal character names is implementation-defined*, like [devx](http://www.devx.com/cplus/10MinuteSolution/34328/1954) mentions. I can not find any reference to implementation defined behavior for this. Only 2.14.3.(5) says something about what to write in the executable, but I can not see anything else.

**Am I right in assuming that a conforming C++11 compiler will therefore *have* support for `\unnnn` and `\Unnnnnnnn`?**

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7081367/printing-universal-characters/7081484#7081484

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand your question fully, but the literal specifiers `u` and `U` only serve to specify the integral data type -- nothing is being said about what constitutes a character (or let alone which encoding is presumed). To summarize:

```
char a1 = 'a', b1[] = "Hello";
wchar_t a2 = L'a', b2[] = L"Hello";
char16_t a3 = u'\u1234', b3[] = u"Hello \uABCD";
char32_t a4 = U'\U5678ABCD', b4[] = U"Hello \U10325476"; // not actually valid codepoints
```

What you ultimately end up *doing* with those types is entirely up to you. The literal specifiers `L`, `u` and `U` simply allow you to put literal constants in your code, and they've been around for some time (though I think the `u"..."` and `U"..."` string syntax is only official in C++0x, and so are the types `char16_t` and `char32_t`, which are genuinely new types, not just aliases).

Comment: Note that `\U10325476` is disallowed in a `char32_t` literal. Only Unicode codepoints, up to 10FFFF, are valid (§2.14.5/15). That is a valid UCN for `wchar_t`, but then again that type might be 16-bit and there is an implementation-defined translation to the execution value. Best to use `\xNNNN` in char32_t strings and `static_cast` instead of non-character character char32_t literals.

Comment: Hehe, you're right, I actually filed a GCC bug report concerning not checking for valid codepoint range ;-) I guess if you need non-codepoint values in your data, you shouldn't really call the data a "string" and use some other type like `uint32_t` to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that it is already the case for C++98.  It is just that conforming compilers on this point are rare.